# Django - quizz system

Tags: python, django

I have created a quizz system. once user selects quiz the value of quiz is stored in session. Next the users get displayed question. I initialized a variable in session which manages question number but it is not working.

```
request.session['qnum'] = 0
```

will this not work ? ??

is there any other way of doing it ?

Comment: How is it not working?

Comment: I tried printing qnum on the template by sending the request in render and displaying it

Comment: <h1>{{ request.session.qnum  }}</h1>

Comment: should have displayed the question number it didn't

Comment: Is the session cookie set in the browser?